# I tried my RestAssured testing code and i am getting the error:

Tags: rest-assured

The errors that i am getting below:

> Blockquote

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipartMode
at io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig.(HttpClientConfig.java:85)
at io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
at io.restassured.RestAssured.(RestAssured.java:421)
at restApiTutorial.basics.main(basics.java:13)
Caused by: {java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode}
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)

Comment: Please try the markdown formatting again. (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Please provide your code. The source of problem is here `restApiTutorial.basics.main(basics.java:13)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.